# Magento Custom Dashboard Redirect

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect, dashboard

I would like to redirect the admin upon login to my **custom module dashboard**. I do not want to override the existing dashboard, but run them in parallel. So I've done the following:

**config.xml:**

```
<admin_session_user_login_success>
    <observers>
        <module>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>custom_dashboard_redirect</method>
        </module>
    </observers>
</admin_session_user_login_success>
```

**Observer.php:**

```
public function custom_dashboard_redirect(){
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('*/custom_dashboard/*'));
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
    exit;
}
```

Unfortunately this seems to simply redirect to the standard dashboard.

**However**, if I redirect to `sales_order` instead of `custom_dashboard`, it does the redirect correctly.

P.S. I can acccess `custom_dashboard` fine through the menu I've created, just not via this redirect. Would appreciate some pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer to the question, but it may be a solution to your problem.
You don't need an event to redirect the admin to a certain page.
There is a setting in the backend where you can set the startup admin page.
Go to `System->Configuration->Admin->Startup Page` and you should see all the menu items in one dropdown. Select your custom dashboard and save.

Comment: Perfect solution to my problem. The fewer events, the better IMO.